# New Column repeating value based on max value from another column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table 'mytable' which has results similar to the below

```
currenttime             racetype            raceid
2018-01-01 03:15:00     gold                22
2018-01-01 04:15:00     silver              22
2019-01-01 04:15:00     bronze              22
2017-01-02 11:44:00     platinum            22
```

I am trying to create another column based on the max current time. It should grab the value of racetype from the max current time and repeate that entry for all items in the new column similar to the below

```
currenttime             racetype          raceid     besttype
2018-01-01 03:15:00     gold              22         bronze
2018-01-01 04:15:00     silver            22         bronze
2019-01-01 04:15:00     bronze            22         bronze
2017-01-02 11:44:00     platinum          22         bronze
```

And if there are other race id's it should do the same for those
 ex

```
currenttime             racetype          raceid     besttype
2018-01-01 03:15:00     gold              22         bronze
2018-01-01 04:15:00     silver            22         bronze
2019-01-01 04:15:00     bronze            22         bronze
2017-01-02 11:44:00     platinum          22         bronze
2011-01-01 03:15:00     gold              09         silver
2022-01-01 04:15:00     silver            09         silver
2002-01-01 04:15:00     bronze            09         silver
```

Currently i have a query

```
select mt.raceid, tt.racetype, MAX(tt.currenttime) 
OVER (PARTITION by mt.raceid) 
from mytable mt 
join tabletwo tt on mt.id = tt.id
where mt.raceid = 22
```

This query is not putting out the expected it is outputting

```
raceid         racetype         col0
22             gold             2019-01-01 04:15:00 
22             silver           2019-01-01 04:15:00 
22             platinum          2019-01-01 04:15:00 
22             bronze           2019-01-01 04:15:00
```

How can i achieve the above expected results shown in the 2nd and 3rd examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**first_value**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) analytic function:

```
select currenttime, racetype, raceid,
       first_value(racetype) over(partition by raceid order by currenttime desc) as besttype
  from mytable
```

Or `last_value`:

```
select currenttime, racetype, raceid,
           last_value(racetype) over(partition by raceid order by currenttime) as besttype
  from mytable
```